# Change fusion style colors in QML dynamically

Tags: qt, qml

I'm developing QML application using Fusion style. I'm using Qt 5.15 lts.
I want to make a function which switch color themes(light mode, dark mode, etc.) in runtime.
The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-fusion.html) says that changing the color system of fusion style can be done by modifying `palette` object in QML.
I believe it will be easily done in `ApplicationWindow` type, but I have to use my custom `Window` object, rather than `ApplicationWindow`.
So I tried to it in C++, like below.

```
// @theme_dark_ and @theme_light_ are pre-defined palette object.
Q_INVOKABLE void Backend::SetDarkMode(const bool flag) {
  qGuiApp->setPalette(flag ? theme_dark_ : theme_light_);
}
```

I checked `setPalette` method works before starting QML application(`QGuiApplication::exec`), but it didn't when QML app is running.
Is there any way to modify `palette` in `Window` type in QML, or calling `QCoreApplication::setPalette` in QML app runtime?
Thanks.

Comment: The documentation says QGuiApplication::setPalette() can be used to set a default palette *before any QML has loaded*. So if you plan on using that method at runtime, you will need to force a reload of all of your QML. Also, a `Window` doesn't have a `palette` property. You need to use `ApplicationWindow` if you want it to recognize the palette.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following example, I have a `Page` component where I can set the `palette` which will be inherited by all its children:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

Page {
    palette: AppPalettes.current
    title: "Palette Demo"

    Flickable {
        id: flickable
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentWidth: columnLayout.width
        contentHeight: columnLayout.height
        clip: true
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            width: 20
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
        }
        
        ColumnLayout {
            id: columnLayout
            width: flickable.width - 40
            CheckBox {
                id: darkMode
                text: checked ? qsTr("Dark Mode") : qsTr("Light Mode")
                checked: AppPalettes.darkMode
                onToggled: AppPalettes.darkMode = checked
            }
            
            Label { text: qsTr("Sample Label") }
            CheckBox { text: qsTr("Sample CheckBox") }
            RadioButton { text: qsTr("Sample Radio Button") }
            Button { text: qsTr("Sample Button") }
            ComboBox {
                Layout.preferredWidth: 200
                model: [ "ComboValue 1", "ComboValue 2", "ComboValue 3" ]
            }
            Slider { from: 0; to: 100 }
            ListView {
                model: 20
                Layout.preferredHeight: contentHeight
                delegate: ItemDelegate {
                    text: "ListItem " + (index + 1)
                    onClicked: ListView.view.currentIndex = index
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}

// qmldir
singleton AppPalettes 1.0 AppPalettes.qml

// AppPalettes.qml
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick
AppPalettesPrivate { }

// AppPalettesPrivate.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
QtObject {
    property bool darkMode: true
    readonly property Palette current: darkMode ? dark : light
    readonly property Palette dark: Palette {
        alternateBase: "#000"
        base: "#000"
        button: "#111"
        buttonText: "#fff"
        dark: "#666"
        highlight: "#d73"
        highlightedText: "#000"
        light: "#000"
        mid: "#444"
        midlight: "#333"
        placeholderText: "#80000000"
        shadow: "#888"
        text: "#fff"
        window: "#222"
        windowText: "#fff"
    }
    readonly property Palette light: Palette {
        alternateBase: "#fff"
        base: "#fff"
        button: "#eee"
        buttonText: "#000"
        dark: "#999"
        highlight: "#38c"
        highlightedText: "#fff"
        light: "#fff"
        mid: "#bbb"
        midlight: "#ccc"
        placeholderText: "#80000000"
        shadow: "#777"
        text: "#000"
        window: "#eee"
        windowText: "#000"
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)